# Software to store frequently used text in PC

Tags: storage, clipboard, text-editing

I am a looking for a free software that can run on the task bar (near the system time) where I can store frequently used text like my full street address, paths of specific deep folders & files in the computer etc etc. This way I can just click the icon which should popup a screen where I should be able to copy the text/string I am looking for

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a "text snippets" utility. Most of the well-known ones are for the Mac, but since you mentioned PC, I found [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) which looks promising.

Comment: thanks. phaseexpress is more of a text expander and is too big in size. I am looking for a tiny program that can store just text/string literals of my frequently used files

Answer (score 1):

[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com)'s Adam Pash wrote an application called [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows), a small text-expander program:

> Windows only: Text substitution app
>   Texter saves you countless keystrokes
>   by replacing abbreviations with
>   commonly used phrases you define.
>
> Unlike software-specific text
>   replacement features, Texter runs in
>   the Windows system tray and works in
>   any application you're typing in.
>   Texter can also set return-to markers
>   for your cursor and insert clipboard
>   contents into your replacement text,
>   in addition to more advanced keyboard
>   macros. Did we mention it's free?
>
> **License:** GNU Public License
>
> **What it does:** Lets you define text substitution hotstrings that, when
>   triggered, will replace hotstring with
>   a larger piece of text. By entering
>   your most commonly-typed snippets of
>   text into Texter, you can save
>   countless keystrokes in the course of
>   the day.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks. i use texter very much for auto-completion. but for frequently used text retrieval i need something where I can pop expand or open and copy the string.

Answer (score 1):

As a clipboard manager [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) is good.

I also have an [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script running which includes abbreviations for commonly used text:

> adr::my address
>
> ema::my email address

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for..  but I use Textpad.  I create a few files ("notes", "passwords", etc) and put links on the task bar so I can get to them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of different programs for commonly-used text, such as various sticky notes applications, text snippet utilities like [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/), and even web browser plugins or panels.  For example, [Opera](http://opera.com) has a Notes panel which is very well integrated with the web browser, and is also searchable.  But you might find something like [EverNote](http://www.evernote.com/) or Microsoft OneNote (if you have MS Office) to be even more useful.

For frequently-used folders, I highly recommend using [DirectFolders](http://www.codesector.com/directfolders.php).  It remembers your recently-used folders for various applications, and you can also add specific folders to the list.  It's really slick, and accessible by double-clicking or middle-clicking in a blank area within any Windows file dialog, folder, or even on the desktop

Comment: thanks. I use ClipX and Evernote in big fashion. clipx only stores history and doesn't store user defined text. evernote is big and not as handy in getting stuff comapred to a tiny app in taskbar next to clock . I am looking for a tiny program that can store just text/string literals of my frequently used files. directfolders is only for folders it looks like

Comment: Points noted on ClipX and Evernote.  I still highly recommend DirectFolders for your folders, however--try it out for a week and see what you think.  Sometimes it's better to use several specialized utilities instead of a single all-in-one utility.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is way late, but I wanted to say that contrary to your comment that [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) only stores clipboard history and not user defined text, ClipX *does* allow user defined text to be stored by using the ClipX Stickies Plugin, found on the same page. I've been using this little program with Stickies for years, and it works exactly as requested in your question.