# Define windows hotkey to auto paste some text

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to store frequently used text in PC](https://superuser.com/questions/131850/software-to-store-frequently-used-text-in-pc)

I want to define a macro to type a string in windows 7.  I remember doing this sort of thing in Windows 95, but I haven't needed it since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking of desktop recording! [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) has something called AutoScriptWriter (recorder) when you install it; it will track what you do and repeat it, even typing lines out.

Answer (score 1):

[ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/) is a very simple tool to remember everything you copy and even display a list or search in the history of your copied items. Maybe it could work for you.